# Mail delivered failed using PHPMailer in PHP

Tags: php, html, email, smtp, phpmailer

Everything is working perfectly if I add anchor tag in HTML mail then mail delivered show failed.

```
include("mail/class.phpmailer.php");
include("mail/class.smtp.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet="UTF-8";
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = 'user@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->From = 'user@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Naren';
$mail->AddAddress('xyz@gmail.com');
//$mail->AddReplyTo('xyz@gmail.com', 'Information');
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject    = "code";
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
$mail->Body    = "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello, This is test mail</p>
<a href='http://www.domain.com/changepassword.php?user_id=" .$User_id1."'>Create your password here</a>
</body>
</html>";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

If I remove the anchor tag from the body then working perfectly but if I add anchor tag then I am getting an email that mail delivered failed. Would you help me in this?

Comment: Do you get any error on error.log ? Try opening the log to see if you have any errors

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Rafael, I am not getting any error message.

Comment: have you add this above your body? $mail->isHTML(true);

Comment: Yes, I added that if you need my full code. i will update it

Comment: If you're getting an *email* saying delivery failed, then you are sending successfully, and your message is probably being bounced by a spam filter. Aside from that you've not really included enough information to go on. Read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide.

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Synchro, I added my full code.

Comment: Add this line and check `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output` what is the error . This line enables the debuggine mode on

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Pranav, I am getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found my answer.I tried below code and It's working perfectly for me.

```
<a href='http://www.domain.com/changepassword.php?user_id=$User_id1'>Create your password here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should close "`a href`" properly, you forgot `'` (single quote)

Instead of:

```
<a href='http://www.domain.com/changepassword.php?user_id=" .$User_id1."'>
```

You should use:

```
<a href='http://www.domain.com/changepassword.php?user_id='" .$User_id1."'>
```

Comment: Since when does that matter? I prefer my id's to be quote-less.

Comment: Mr.Sylwester, I am getting email in spam now

Comment: Mr.Xorifelse, Can you help me out in this?